php imap_open cannot make a secure connection to a virtualmin dovecot server on port 143 with tls
*** update ***
This might be due to the PHP open_imap function itlself after finding this post here
This issue when this php file is on the server itself, there is no problems and it connects to the email.
However, when I test this on my local machine on macBook, it gives me the error below (SSL negotiation failed)

server log files I can see it tries to connect (no firewall issue)
PHP versions are almost the same (server 8.3) local w/ brew (8.2)
I have thunderbird connected to this server on port 143

I have a virtual server running on virtualmin with dovecot as IMAP and the only port open is 143.
I have let's encrypt certificate and everything has been running fine on this server for email with Dovecot and Postfix
root@web:~# postconf mail_version
mail_version = 3.5.25

root@web:~# dovecot --version
2.3.13 (89f716dc2)

Debian Linux 11
Webmin version  2.202
Virtualmin version  7.20.2


I am using PHP 8.2 with brew on a macbook.  I use the following start of script to connect to the server
$imap = imap_open('{domain.ca:143/tls}INBOX', 'username', 'password');

var_dump(imap_last_error());exit;

I keep getting a SSL negotiation failed regardless of /tls, /ssl or ssl/novalidate-cert.  I have tried every combination and setting from the php manual.  I have tried every solution on stack or online without any success.
I also tried directly by the public IP.  Postfix and dovecot are on domain.ca, not imap.domain.ca if that matters.
Warning: imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {domain.ca:143/tls}INBOX in /usr/local/var/www/index.php on line 5
string(58) "TLS/SSL failure for domain.ca: SSL negotiation failed"
Notice: PHP Request Shutdown: TLS/SSL failure for domain.ca: SSL negotiation failed (errflg=2) in Unknown on line 0

server journalctl says
ay 10 11:34:57 web.domain.ca dovecot[828]: imap-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=x.x.x.x, lip=x.x.x.x, session=<qg0rRxsY/IVGNc6I>

so from what this log says, am I using this wrong?  Should have have the auth. inside the '{domain.ca:143/notls}' string?  Or is this php extension configured not to check secure connect on 143?
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you

Have you checked the SSL certificate on the port 143?

yes by doing openssl s_client -connect domain.ca:143 -starttls imap and everything seems fine with both 143 and 587
